# strip url to base url in excel / google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Ive been working with the below excel / google drive spreadsheets function that allows you to take a url, strip the protocol (eg http://), strip the www, and strip any info after the TLD. The function is :

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("//www.",A2)), MID(A2,FIND(":",A2,4)+3,FIND("/",A2,9)-FIND(":",A2,4)-3), MID(A2,FIND(":",A2,4)+7,FIND("/",A2,9)-FIND(":",A2,4)-7))
```

It works great but if a URL is already bare eg. **example.com** the function throws an error, it also throws an error if the url is dosnt have a trailing slash, or a slash before the domain name (for example in http://). Ive tried several ways to check if the url is already bare, by checking if the cell contains : `http://, https://, ftp://, www. etc..` but this seems overly complex and fragile.

Is there a better way to do this ?

For testing ive made a google spreadsheet here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IVe-VqZtqBtyobBzVHBIm2WQYCvynKZonxK_uEZvXDc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a single regex function in google sheets:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)")
```

or with iferror in case the cell is blank:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^\/]+)"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Aurielle Perlmann that works if there is no `http://`, `https://` etc, but if there is it only extracts `:` see attached spreadsheet (need to go to tab2) - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IVe-VqZtqBtyobBzVHBIm2WQYCvynKZonxK_uEZvXDc/edit#gid=1300152513

Comment: sorry typo - I fixed - was trying to include the ftp you mentioned in your question - but I personally rarely come across those and I clean millions of domains during stuff I do at work every day - the one up top that I modified works for every example

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

Comment if you have any other doubts

=iferror(IF(find("/",A11)<8,INDEX(SPLIT(A11,"//"),1,2),IF(FIND("/",A11)>8,INDEX(SPLIT(A11,"//"),1,1),0)),A12)

Comment: Thanks @harshavardhan, this works to strip the base url of www. , http:// etc, but breaks if it encounters anything after the tld like a sub directory of subpage

Comment: Now check the answer

Comment: Just noticed that the script dosnt strip www. from the urls, in the past ive been using this `=IF(LEFT(A2,4)="www.", RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-4), A2)
` to do that so ive just set that up in the next column